# Flutter go_router simply does not navigate?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes

I implemented go_router into my app today. I don't really have much to say except that it just does not navigate if I call `context.go('/main')`. No error, nothing.

This is my GoRouter Object in the MaterialApp Widget in the main.dart file:

```
GoRouter(
        redirect: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
          if (isAlreadyLoggedIn == null) return '/loading';
          if (isAlreadyLoggedIn!) {
            return '/main';
          } else {
            return '/';
          }
        },
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
              path: '/',
              builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(title: 'Login')),
          GoRoute(
              path: '/main',
              builder: (context, state) =>
                  const MainPage(title: 'Dashboard')),
          GoRoute(
            path: '/loading',
            builder: (context, state) => const LoadingPage(),
          )
        ]));
```

If have an Auth Flow, which checks if the User was already logged In. If yes, the User is redirected to the main Page (works here properly). If not, the User needs to login. If succeeded, I want to navigate to main. And here nothing happens.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you will need to implement `refreshListenable` on `GoRouter`, this field will notify to `GoRouter` when `isAlreadyLoggedIn` changed.
You can read more at [here](https://github.com/csells/go_router/discussions/122)